# Delaying startup until c# lauched browser is closed

Tags: c#

I have an application that runs at user login and checks the users password expiration if the password was just changed the program will open up a browser.  After the user interfaces with the website and closes it I want windows to continue booting.  Is there anyway to halt the system startup until the browser is closed from c#?

Comment: What is the purpose of your app ?

Comment: If your app runs at user login, then then the computer has already booted. I take it you meant "suspend the login process in some way". Windows has all sorts of things to do with logins, password expiry etc. built in - why would they come to your website for something they've already got?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you opening the browser?

You can start a new process and keep a handle to it.  Then you can call `Process.WaitForExit();`

I haven't had a chance to test it - but I believe you can do this:

```
var myProcess = new Process 
{
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo 
    {
        FileName = "http://www.whatever.com"
    }
};
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();
```

I believe this will start the default browser and wait for you to close it.  You can also listen for an exit event - but I think this is what you are asking for.